# Java RegEx replace

Tags: java

I need to use a replace function in Java:
`string.replace(myString,"");`
myString values are for example `javascript:r(0)`, `javascript:r(23)`, `javascript:l(5)` etc. Just number is always different and there is `r` or `l` letter. What's the regular expression to match it? Thanks

Comment: Feel free to do some tests by yourself [here](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm)

Comment: Did you try anything? At all?

Comment: yea but I don't understand regex expressions very well. I tried some online tools but it didn't work. And also I'm new to Java. Now I have the expression but finding the way how to use it :/

Comment: try \b(javascript[:][rl][(][0-9][0-9][)]) it matches from from r/l(0) to r/l(99)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(FIXED) The regex you want is

```
"javascript:[rl]\\(\\d+\\)"
```

NOTE: The outer quotes aren't really part of the regex; they are part of the Java string you pass to `Pattern.compile` or directly to `replace`.

Here is a complete program you can try:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class PatternExample {
    private static final Pattern JS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("javascript:[rl]\\(\\d+\\)");
    private static final String[] MESSAGES = {
        "Good javascript:r(5)",
        "Good javascript:l(50003843)",
        "Good javascript:r(1123934)",
        "Bad javascript:|(5)",
        "Bad javascript:r(53d)",
        "Bad javascript:l()",
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s : MESSAGES) {
            Matcher matcher = JS_PATTERN.matcher(s);
            System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(""));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is another version of the above program that calls `replaceAll` *directly* on the string instead of pre-compiling the pattern:

```
public class PatternExample {
    private static final String[] MESSAGES = {
        "Good javascript:r(0)",
        "Good javascript:l(50003843)",
        "Good javascript:r(1123934)",
        "Bad javascript:|(5)",
        "Bad javascript:r(53d)",
        "Bad javascript:l()",
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s : MESSAGES) {
            System.out.println(s.replaceAll("javascript:[rl]\\(\\d+\\)", ""));
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: I passed it directly to `replace` ( `str = str.replace("javascript:[rl]\(\d+\)", "");` ) but it gives me errors (Eclipse) `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Comment: Right, @simPod, that's what I get for trying to write more than "just the regex" and not testing it.  If it's gonna be in a Java string, the backslashes have to be escaped.  Very sorry. Edited.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Now there's no error... But it doesn't work... I have this code: `String str = "javascript:r(0)"; str = str.replace("javascript:[rl]\\(\\d+\\)", "");` result is still `javascript:r(0)`. The RegExPlanet says it matches. I don't understand why replace function doesn't work (???)

Comment: I added the traditional Pattern/Matcher approach to my answer... let me also add the direct replace approach on your string as well.

Comment: @simPod I added a full program which includes your exact case.  Hope you can get it working.

Comment: ouch, this works! I didn't know I have to use Matcher. So, thanks a lot!

Comment: It works both ways, @simPod.  You don't _have_ to use a matcher but it is recommended if you are going to apply the same regex over and over again.  When you say `s.replaceAll(p, t)` for a pattern `p`, it will compile the regex.  So if you call `replace` multiple times, things will work fine but it is compiling the regex over and over.

Comment: Ah, ok. In this case it's better to use Matcher. There's a lot of replacing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

The following regex will match it:

```
javascript:[rl]\(\d+\)
```

Comment: Whoops, close: the `|` inside the square brackets is matched. :)