# How to find a matching query string and replace in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm getting the RSS feeds from a wordpress blog where I get the thumbnail image in the string. Below is the sample feed i get

> <img src="http://www.example.com/some-image.jpg?resize=50%2C50"
>   class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="SomeImage"
>   style="margin:0px;" />

I need to remove "**?resize=50%2C50**" from the image source. But the problem is I can't hardcode this in my code as the size may not remain the same. Also the order in which the attributes are placed may change

How can I simply remove anything that matches this pattern so that I can always get the output as

> <img src="http://www.example.com/some-image.jpg"
>   class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Some Image"
>   style="margin:0px;" />

Thanks in advance

Comment: what did you try so far? what problem did you face? Or you just want us to write a code for you?

Comment: Is it alright if the trailing `?` is still there, i.e. `some-image.jpg?" class="`

Comment: The images are always in jpg format?

Comment: Since the "?resize="-part stays the same you should have no problem to find it.

Comment: I think the following answer will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018952/java-regex-replace

Answer (score 0):

RegEx to capture your image: `src=(".+\.jpg)(\?resize\S+")`
Can then replace with `src=\$1"`

```
    String url="<img src=\"http://www.example.com/some-image.jpg?resize=50%2C50\" class=\"attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image\" alt=\"SomeImage\" style=\"margin:0px;\" />";
    final String regex="src=(\".+\\.jpg)(\\?resize\\S+\")";
    url = url.replaceFirst(regex, "src=$1\"");

    System.out.println(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want only the path up to the params, so:

```
String str = "<img src=\"http://www.example.com/some-image.jpg?resize=50%2C50\" class=\"attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image\" alt=\"SomeImage\" style=\"margin:0px;\" />";
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("(\\?\\S[^\"]+)", ""));
```

This will output:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/some-image.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="SomeImage" style="margin:0px;" />
```